# Javascript key/value pair with no braces

Tags: javascript, node.js

I noticed that in both nodejs and a browser, you can give a key/value pair with no braces, and it is accepted. It evaluates to the value half of the pair. For instance:

```
> { id: 5 }
{ id: 5 }
> id: 5
5
```

But if you quote `id`, then node wants more input:

```
> "id": 5
...
```

So what is going on here? What syntax is `id: 5` when it has no braces?

Comment: In your question, `id` is a label. Not the key portion of a key-value pair.

Comment: That would be a label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug. You are declaring a label, followed by a `Number` literal.

The console defaults to printing out the result of the last expression in your code.

Hence it prints `5`.

Your confusion stems from the fact that **the exact same syntax can mean totally different things, depending on the context**.

This is for the JavaScript parser to decide according to the rules of the spec.

Another example would be:

```
{}
```

Is that an object literal or a block? The context provides the answer.

From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-LabelledStatement):

> A Statement may be prefixed by a label. Labelled statements are only
>   used in conjunction with labelled break and continue statements.
>   ECMAScript has no goto statement. A Statement can be part of a
>   LabelledStatement, which itself can be part of a LabelledStatement,
>   and so on. The labels introduced this way are collectively referred to
>   as the “current label set” when describing the semantics of individual
>   statements.

Comment: If you like parser ambiguity trivia, the actual code motivating this question was `if (foo) { id: 5 }`.

Comment: How about: `() => {}`

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you've written a nested `for..loop`.

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    if(thereIsAProblem) {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log('done a column');
}
```

You want to break out of the inner loop and start the next iteration of the outer loop, but you don't want the `console.log` to run.

You can augment the loop with a label to specify exactly where you want to continue from.

```
outer: for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    if(thereIsAProblem) {
      continue outer;
    }
  }
  console.log('done a column');
}
```

Although technically this is a standard feature in JavaScript, you won't see it used in the wild very often, because there's almost always a more idiomatic way to do things.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a bug of the JavaScript parser. When you type `id : anything : 5` it outputs the same result (this works on Chrome too).